# Maximum Number of modes of $V=U+Z$ where $Z$ standard normal and $|U|\le a$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

Let $f_V$ be a pdf of  random variable $V$ where
\begin{align}
V=U+Z
\end{align}
and where $U$ and $Z$ are independent and $Z$ is Gaussian. Moreover, suppose that $|U| \le A$.

Can we find the upper bound on the number of modes of $V$?

Note that the the pdf $V$ is given by 
\begin{align}
f_V(v)=E\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(v-U)^2}{2}}\right]
\end{align}

I am actually not interested in a very tight bound. I more interested in the methods that can be used to produce such bounds.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\renewcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\tf}{\widetilde{f}}$

The pdf $f_V$ is a mixture of the family $\F_A:=(f_a)_{a\in[-A,A]}$ of the normal pdfs $f_a$ with mean $a$ and variance $1$. By Theorem 6 on p. 2129 of [Kemperman](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176348389), for each natural $s$, the pdf $f_V$ will have at most $s$ modes (or, more precisely, modal intervals) iff any mixture of any $2s$ members of the family $\F_A$ has at most $s$ modal intervals.

This theorem is a generalization of Theorem 4 on p. 2128 of [Kemperman](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176348389), which implies that all mixtures of a family of pdfs are unimodal iff any mixture of any two members of the family is unimodal.

Further, by Remark 1 on p. 2133 of [Kemperman](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176348389), our pdf $f_V$ will be unimodal for all admissible $U$ iff for all $a,b,x$ such that $-A\le a<x<b\le A$ we have
\begin{equation}
 f'_a(x)f''_b(x)\ge f'_b(x)f''_a(x), 
\end{equation}
which can be rewritten as $(a-x)(b-x)\ge-1$ for all such $a,b,x$, which is equivalent to $A\le1$.

The case of more modes than $1$ appears much more difficult analytically.